# how to find out actual url link

Tags: url

how to find the actual link behind a php id link , For example , i have a  link like www.website.php?id=2 , how do find out the actual link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is server-side scripting. When you access a page fed by a script, the web server runs that script and dynamically generates HTML or other client-side code for your browser to render.

The only file being referenced in, say, `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=2` is the PHP script index.php. The content of the webpage you're viewing could come from any number of things, including a database server, the script itself, or other scripts (or files, which may or may not be public-URI-accessible). The script decides which content to output based on the id=2 argument.

The point of server-side scripting is that you, the user, aren't supposed to know what's going on. So, 9 times out of 10, the PHP link you see is the "actual" link—there's simply no other way to get that content as a public web browser.

The other 1 time out of 10 might be something with shortURLs or redirects, but we'd need more specific information to figure something like that out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no link behind it and the page is generated on the fly by a dynamic website.

Comment: There must be a way,
If something comes this side we should be able to go that side too